# How do i prove invertibility of this linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from a vector space $V$  over reals into $V$ such that $T-T^2=I$. Show that $T$ is invertible

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

\begin{align}
I = T - T^2 &= T \circ (I - T) \\
&= (I - T) \circ T
\end{align}

Comment: so $I-T$ is inverse of T, thanks :)